# Match successive overlapping groups with regex

Tags: regex, awk, grep, overlap, regex-lookarounds

I have strings like:

```
TAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTA
```

I can do

```
$ echo TAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTA | grep -Eo "[ACGT]{4}"
TAAC
CCTA
ACCC
TAAC
CCTA
```

But I would like:

```
TAAC
AACC
ACCC
CCCT
CCTA
...
...
```

It must have something to do with non-greedy and lookaheads or lookbehinds, but I need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo TAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTA | awk '{while (d++ < length) print substr($0, d, 4)}'
```

Comment: Thanks! That totally works with one alteration. Need `length-3` or get some stubs at the end. I was hoping for a regex solution.

Comment: @abalter why use a zebra when a horse will do?

Comment: To learn more about regex, and perhaps need something similar but different in the future. But good to learn more awk as well, and your answer is clean and simple.